# VB DateAdd to String

Tags: vb.net, photoshop, tostring, dateadd

Im trying to get the DateAdd function as a string

So far i got

```
Dim newDate 
newDate = DateAdd("m", 1, date)
MsgBox(newDate.ToString("d"))
```

Which gets error object required

Im trying to create a photoshop script that gets the date and adds on 1 month then writes to the active text layer

```
'Get and Change Expiry Date 
docRef.ActiveLayer = docRef.Layers(3)
Set textItemRef = docRef.ActiveLayer.TextItem

Dim newDate 
newDate = DateAdd("m", 1, date)
textItemRef.Contents = newDate.ToString("d")
```

Any help will be great

Comment: A VBScript date variable does not have a `ToString` method.  Are you actually trying to code VB.Net instead of VBScript?

Comment: I have just used `""&DateAdd("m", 6, date)` but if there is a better way please tell me

Comment: Thanks @HansUp New to VB and coming from PHP alil confused

Answer (score 0):

A string in VBA is not an object so has no `ToString()` method, that's VB.NET.

```
newDate = DateAdd("m", 1, date)
MsgBox newDate
```

or

```
MsgBox format$(newDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```